# Azure: Microsoft.Compute resource provider stuck 'Registering' for about a day

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-container-service, azure-aks

I've tried un-registering and re-registering and it just keeps getting stuck. No logs I can see so I'm not really sure what to do...

Has anyone experienced this before?

Comment: do you really care about that? can you create vms or whatever you need to do with microsoft.compute? raise a support ticket.

Comment: I care because this error is stopping me using AKS (Kubernetes). Every time I try to create it it fails with an error about missing Microsoft.Compute

Comment: do you have rights to perform registration? try deregister\reregister. Usually it happens in 2 minutes maximum

Comment: I definitely have the rights, It's a brand new account and I'm the only user. I've tried un-register a couple of times, but then it just gets stuck Unregistering instead. I've left it for a couple of hours and theres still no change unfortunately

Comment: I think you only have 2 options: support or wait. Or create a new account

Comment: Yeah, I've contacted support so hoping they can do something at their end. Thanks for the help though!

Comment: Exact same issue here @AdamNiles-CraneWalker Did you ever hear back on this one?

Comment: @Necevil It's all good now, got a support ticket and it got sorted. I think it was a system wide issue which has been resolved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that there was some issue, which is now mitigated. Check your Service Health/Resource Health page.

The ‘Service Health’ - Service issues view shows any ongoing problems in Azure services that are impacting your resources. You can understand when the issue began, and what services and regions are impacted. You can also read the most recent update to understand what Azure is doing to resolve the issue.

Resource health helps you diagnose and get support when an Azure issue impacts your resources. It informs you about the current and past health of your resources and helps you mitigate issues. Resource health provides technical support when you need help with Azure service issues.

Reference:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-health/resource-health-overview

Answer (score 1):

If its a brand new subscription i always like to deploy a new Resource manager VM to register all the required resource provider. Once the VM deploys OKs then you can try the AKS (Kubernetes) deployment.

Note: you might still need to register Microsoft.ContainerService for AKS

While you wait for support you can try that an see. Don't forget to delete the VM.

Comment: Gave that a go, still no dice. Get the same error when provisioning the AKS :  "code": "PreconditionFailed",
  "message": "Required resource provider registrations Microsoft.Compute are missing."

Comment: Did the VM deploy OK?

Comment: Yeah the VM deployed absolutely fine but cant deploy AKS, makes no sense at all :(

Comment: @Hannel Good thought but no solution for the same issue on my side, thumbs up for the idea (and because I accidentally thumbs downed you hah!).  Created the VM in the same Resource Group but no change to Microsoft.Compute registration (all other providers register normally).

Comment: Microsoft.Compute is required for VM, so if the VM is getting deployed but not AKS is failing with Microsoft.Compute error it means a sub feature within the provide is failing. Support will be the only one that can assist in fixing that.

Comment: Just deployed AKS successfully. Just to make sure we are covering all bases can you provide the commands you are running?

[img]https://i.imgur.com/ffNcEBS.png[/img]

Comment: It's all good now, got a support ticket and it got sorted. I think it was a system wide issue which has been resolved

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be an issue that pops up on occasion. As far as I can tell there's no self-service way to fix this when it happens, and your only recourse is to file a support request via the Azure Portal here: https://portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_Azure_Support/HelpAndSupportBlade/overview