# 'Microsoft.Compute' Azure Resource Provider never finishes 'Registering':

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-aks

This issue is SOMEWHAT similar to the following (but does not display the same behavior in testing):

1. [Azure: Microsoft.Compute resource provider stuck 'Registering' for about a day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50437947/azure-microsoft-compute-resource-provider-stuck-registering-for-about-a-day)

> While attempting to register the Microsoft.Compute provider in order
>   to use AKS from the MacOS command line (or alternately Cloud Shell
>   from within Azure), the provider takes an exorbitantly long time to
>   finish registering.

At the time of this writing it is still in the 'registering' status 6 hours later.

### What is supposed to happen normally?

The following command should register Microsoft.Compute in a timely manner:

`az provider register -n Microsoft.Compute`

### What goes wrong?

The provider never registers and continuously hangs "Registering" when it's status is checked with the following command:

```
az provider show --namespace Microsoft.Compute -o table
```

The response to the above shell command looks like this (and has for 6 hours or so):

```
Namespace          RegistrationState

-----------------  -------------------

Microsoft.Compute  Registering
```

Other Providers that Registered Successfully:

- Microsoft.Network
- Microsoft.Storage
- Microsoft.ContainerService

Given the above (and the fact that I am the root / only user) it is likely not a permissions issue since those providers would have failed.  Under 'My Permissions' I am listed as administrator: 'You are an administrator on the subscription' see the below screen shot of registered providers (with permissions blade on the right):

[image]

Since the provider never finishes registering, attempting to create a Cluster with AKS of course fails with:

***Operation failed with status: 'Bad Request'. Details: Required resource provider registrations Microsoft.Compute are missing.***

### Other Background:

Two days ago I preformed the identical operations on a clients account successfully and everything finished within 5 minutes.  I have tried the following options to solve the issue (thus far with no impact):

1. A user on Stack Overflow (here: [Azure: Microsoft.Compute resource provider stuck 'Registering' for about a day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50437947/azure-microsoft-compute-resource-provider-stuck-registering-for-about-a-day)) suggested spinning a VM within the resource group / account in the hopes that would solve the issue and register the provider automatically (this did not work).
2. **Un-register the Provider**
   This is where my situation diverges from the above question.  When unregistering the component with: 
   `az provider unregister -n Microsoft.Compute`
   I get:
   ***The subscription cannot be unregistered from resource namespace 'Microsoft.Compute'. Please delete existing resources for the provider.***

This is different from the user over here who then gets Stuck / Hangs at Un-Registering, as opposed to failing with the above message when attempting to unregister ([Azure: Microsoft.Compute resource provider stuck 'Registering' for about a day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50437947/azure-microsoft-compute-resource-provider-stuck-registering-for-about-a-day))

I am hoping that someone has encountered this in the past.
At this point I am going to try to delete my subscription (which was created earlier in the day) and add a new one / repeat.

Will post back with my findings.

Comment: I have a similar issue when attempting to create a Web App. The Microsoft.Web provider is stuck in the Registering state. Do you recall when the reps advised?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This specific issue was faced by multiple users across the globe and has been fixed, try and see if it works fine now.

Comment: You are right on Zahid, I don't know whether it was a global fix that solved the problem or the reps that I talked to through my trouble ticket but either way I am all set as of this afternoon!

Comment: This has been then poorly implemented fix as the situation occurs again and I'm apparently not alone with the issue recently: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/f86d8c20-6a66-4690-8ddf-131bf4bdbe61/service-providers-microsoftstorage-stuck-at-registering?forum=smallbasic

Answer (score 0):

I recently had the same issue with registration of the Microsoft.Web Provider.
Once I registered it using a specific API version (via CloudShell, while it was still in status "registering") it immediately registered successfully.
This is the command I used:

```
Register-AzResourceProvider -ProviderNamespace Microsoft.Web -ApiVersion "2023-01-01"
```